# Distinct random numbers between 0:1

Tags: c, random

I am new to programing and i would like a script where it gives me 4 distinct random numbers between 0:1 so i could use pythagoras and make an average value of it. After some tries i managed to create numbers between 0:1, however they are all the same value, how do i make them diferent from each other? Sorry for my bad english.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    int x1,x2,y1,y2,sum,pythagoras;

    //x1,x2,y1,y2 must be different values
    //sum = (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2
    //pythagoras = sqrt(soma)

    int tempo = time(NULL);
    srand(time);
    double number = ((double) rand() * 2) / ( double ) RAND_MAX;
    printf("x1 = %.3f", number);
    printf("  x2 = %.3f", number);
    printf("  y1 = %.3f", number);
    printf("  y2 = %.3f", number);
}
```

thanks in advance.

My question is about:

Comment: loop 4 times where you call `rand()`

Comment: Think a little about what you're doing. Try to explain it to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), and see if it really makes sense.

Comment: You appear to be treating `double number = ((double) rand() * 2) / ( double ) RAND_MAX;` like a definition of a function, and think that the `printf`s are the assignments. This is not the case, not even close.

Answer (score 2):

You only made one random number and printed it 4 times.

When you do this:

```
double number = ((double) rand() * 2) / ( double ) RAND_MAX;
```

It doesn't mean than anytime you use `number` that it will execute the above statement.  It means that it happens *once*, when you do it.

If you want 4 random number, you need to call `rand` 4 times:

```
double number = ((double) rand() * 2) / ( double ) RAND_MAX;
printf("x1 = %.3f", number);
number = ((double) rand() * 2) / ( double ) RAND_MAX;
printf("  x2 = %.3f", number);
number = ((double) rand() * 2) / ( double ) RAND_MAX;
printf("  y1 = %.3f", number);
number = ((double) rand() * 2) / ( double ) RAND_MAX;
printf("  y2 = %.3f", number);
```

What you *can* do as a "formula" is to create a function:

```
double rand_number()
{
    return (double) rand() * 2) / ( double ) RAND_MAX;
}
```

Then you can call this function when you need it:

```
printf("x1 = %.3f", rand_number());
printf("  x2 = %.3f", rand_number());
printf("  y1 = %.3f", rand_number());
printf("  y2 = %.3f", rand_number());
```

Comment: Why not assign the `rand()`s to the variables `x1, y1, x2, y2` instead?

Comment: @AntonH: Mainly because the original code didn't get anywhere close to doing that.